# association bonus already at 199 reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, association

today, an update on stackoverflow brought my reputation there from 189 to 199 and then i got the association bonus. i'm definitely not complaining, but didn't you need (at least) 200 reputation for the bonus?

Comment: You have probably gotten an upvote that was reversed, putting you at 209 for a short while, granting you the association bonus.

Comment: hmm, possible, but not all that likely as all my answers are under the not-much-frequented ember.js tag and i was checking the page quite often today... ah well, maybe the OP accepted the wrong answer by mistake. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your http://stackoverflow.com/users/2048165/finn-maccool is having `299` reputation points..

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - Yes, after the association bonus. Without it, it would be 199.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15913542/timeline):

> [image]

The timestamp match perfectly the association bonus time:

> [image]

:)